# Selecting rows where ids are provided in a list

Tags: php, pdo

I want to get all the list of registered players from an array

here is my function

```
function UpdateContact() 
    {
        try {
            $conn = $this->GetDBConnection();

            $linkedInId = trim($_REQUEST['linkedInId']);

            $statement = $conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET linkedInId = :linkedInId WHERE linkedInId = :linkedInId');
            $statement->bindParam(':linkedInId', $linkedInId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->execute();

            //$updatedTime = time() - 120;
            $ids = implode(",",$_POST['ids']);
// $ids = (abc,def,geh,ijk,lac);

            $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE linkedInId IN (:ids)');
            $statement->execute($ids);
            $conn = null;

            if (!($row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) 
                return false;
            else
                return $row;    

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
            throw $e;
        }       
    }
```

Just return false

Maybe because i am not able to bind the array with PDO Statement?

How can I fix this solution, i might want to add more binding parameters too later on, so i don't want  to do `execute($ids)` either.

I have tried `bindParam(':ids',$ids)` too but of no avail

```
$items = array();
            //$statement->bindParam(':updatedTime', $updatedTime, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            foreach ($id as $ids)
            {
                $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
                $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->execute();
                if(($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))) 
                    $items[] = $id;
            }
```

Comment: [How can I create a prepared statement for IN () operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15991146) and [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: Are you sure there exists an entry with the provided id?

Comment: yes i am SURE of it @Jonast92

Comment: @Jonast92, I think you are right, and the problem seems to be with the update statement. In my opinion no records will be updated.

Comment: what it has to do with update Statement? Update statement is for another purpose.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I think you try to update the ids where they already have the new value. This makes no sense to me. And this is why I thought you have no records with the given ids.

Comment: @AndrasToth That update just updates timestamp :) Has nothing to do with updated value.

Comment: I see. Then ignore my comments.

Comment: -1 to make this question less relevant in search as accepted answer is obviously wrong.

Comment: @YourCommonSense kindly provide me ur solution

Comment: You know, I did it already. With very first comment. For both problems you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would make more sense to parse the array/list and perform the select for each id in the array/list.

Pseudo code:

```
init resultArray;
For x in List
    select * from database where ids =: x
    if result
        add result to resultArray
return resultArray
```

But that's just the basic way of doing it, I'm not sure if you can do it more advanced.

Comment: Can you check my code edited. is that what u are saying. can you edit it accordingly. I am not expert in php. Make sure $ids is set by implode.

Comment: perfect, i did a couple of changes and now its fine :) thanks

Comment: this won't make any sense. one have to select all the required data with single query when possible

Comment: I would love to get it in one query if you can solve it